# Flutter - The getter 'value' was called on null

Tags: flutter, camera, save, sharedpreferences, settings

I'm trying to save to SharedPreferences the current camera selected. When the app restarts, I would like the same camera to be used initially. If the user toggles to another camera, that camera gets saved.

When I have the following code in the initState, I get the "The getter 'value' was called on null." error message. Also the red/yellow error messages show up and disappear quickly before the camera starts working.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    try {
      SharedPreferencesHelper prefs = SharedPreferencesHelper();
      prefs.getCameraSelected().then((String answer) {
        if (answer != null) {
          if (answer == 'back') {
            onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
          } else {
            onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
          }
        } else {
          print('answer is null');
          onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

If I replace the initState back to the original state, everything works as expected

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    try {
      onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Below is the full code for the CameraHomeScreen.dart file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CameraHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  CameraHomeScreen(this.cameras);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CameraHomeScreenState();
  }
}

class _CameraHomeScreenState extends State<CameraHomeScreen> {
  String imagePath;
  bool _toggleCamera = false;
  String _currentCamera = 'back';
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    try {
      SharedPreferencesHelper prefs = SharedPreferencesHelper();
      prefs.getCameraSelected().then((String answer) {
        if (answer != null) {
          print('here');
          print(answer);
          if (answer == 'back') {
            onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
          } else {
            onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
          }
        } else {
          print('answer is null');
          onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(
          'No Camera Found',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CameraPreview(controller),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 120.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(00, 00, 00, 0.7),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                          onTap: () {
                            _captureImage();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/ic_shutter_1.png',
                              width: 72.0,
                              height: 72.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                          onTap: () {
                            if (!_toggleCamera) {
                              SharedPreferencesHelper prefs =
                                  SharedPreferencesHelper();
                              prefs.setCameraSelected('front');
                              onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
                              setState(() {
                                _toggleCamera = true;
                              });
                            } else {
                              SharedPreferencesHelper prefs =
                                  SharedPreferencesHelper();
                              prefs.setCameraSelected('back');
                              onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
                              setState(() {
                                _toggleCamera = false;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/ic_switch_camera_3.png',
                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                              width: 42.0,
                              height: 42.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) await controller.dispose();
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.medium);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        showMessage('Camera Error: ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      showException(e);
    }

    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }

  String timestamp() => new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  void _captureImage() {
    takePicture().then((String filePath) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imagePath = filePath;
        });
        if (filePath != null) {
          showMessage('Picture saved to $filePath');
          setCameraResult();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void setCameraResult() {
    Navigator.pop(context, imagePath);
  }

  Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showMessage('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/FlutterDevs/Camera/Images';
    await new Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      showException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  void showException(CameraException e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
    showMessage('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }

  void showMessage(String message) {
    print(message);
  }

  void logError(String code, String message) =>
      print('Error: $code\nMessage: $message');
}

class SharedPreferencesHelper {
  ///
  /// Instantiation of the SharedPreferences library
  ///
  final String _nameKey = "cameraSelected";

  /// ------------------------------------------------------------
  /// Method that returns the user decision on sorting order
  /// ------------------------------------------------------------
  Future<String> getCameraSelected() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.getString(_nameKey) ?? 'name';
  }

  /// ----------------------------------------------------------
  /// Method that saves the user decision on sorting order
  /// ----------------------------------------------------------
  Future<bool> setCameraSelected(String value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.setString(_nameKey, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: On your initial code, the try and catch will not run since you're not doing "await onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Use `SharedPreferences` before `runApp(MyApp());` 
and `class CameraHomeScreen` add a parameter for `initCamera` 
and use it like this `CameraHomeScreen(cameras, initCamera)`,

code snippet

```
String initCamera;
List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  SharedPreferences pre = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //await prefs.setString("cameraSelected","front");
  initCamera = await pre.getString("cameraSelected");
  print('initCamera ${initCamera}');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
...
class CameraHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  String initCamera;

  CameraHomeScreen(this.cameras, this.initCamera);
... 
void initState() {
    print( 'widget.initCamera ${widget.initCamera}' );
    if (widget.initCamera == 'back') {
      onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
    } else {
      onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
    }

    super.initState();
  }
```

demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

String initCamera;
List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  SharedPreferences pre = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //await prefs.setString("cameraSelected","front");
  initCamera = await pre.getString("cameraSelected");
  print('initCamera ${initCamera}');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CameraHomeScreen(cameras, initCamera),
    );
  }
}


class CameraHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  String initCamera;

  CameraHomeScreen(this.cameras, this.initCamera);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CameraHomeScreenState();
  }
}

class _CameraHomeScreenState extends State<CameraHomeScreen> {
  String imagePath;
  bool _toggleCamera = false;
  String _currentCamera = 'back';
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print( 'widget.initCamera ${widget.initCamera}' );
    if (widget.initCamera == 'back') {
      onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
    } else {
      onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(
          'No Camera Found',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CameraPreview(controller),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 120.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(00, 00, 00, 0.7),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                          onTap: () {
                            _captureImage();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/ic_shutter_1.png',
                              width: 72.0,
                              height: 72.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                          onTap: () {
                            if (!_toggleCamera) {
                              SharedPreferencesHelper prefs =
                                  SharedPreferencesHelper();
                              prefs.setCameraSelected('front');
                              print("front");
                              onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[1]);
                              setState(() {
                                _toggleCamera = true;
                              });
                            } else {
                              SharedPreferencesHelper prefs =
                                  SharedPreferencesHelper();
                              prefs.setCameraSelected('back');
                              print("back");
                              onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
                              setState(() {
                                _toggleCamera = false;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/ic_switch_camera_3.png',
                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                              width: 42.0,
                              height: 42.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) await controller.dispose();
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.medium);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        showMessage('Camera Error: ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      showException(e);
    }

    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }

  String timestamp() => new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  void _captureImage() {
    takePicture().then((String filePath) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imagePath = filePath;
        });
        if (filePath != null) {
          showMessage('Picture saved to $filePath');
          setCameraResult();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void setCameraResult() {
    Navigator.pop(context, imagePath);
  }

  Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showMessage('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/FlutterDevs/Camera/Images';
    await new Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      showException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  void showException(CameraException e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
    showMessage('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }

  void showMessage(String message) {
    print(message);
  }

  void logError(String code, String message) =>
      print('Error: $code\nMessage: $message');
}

class SharedPreferencesHelper {
  ///
  /// Instantiation of the SharedPreferences library
  ///
  final String _nameKey = "cameraSelected";

  /// ------------------------------------------------------------
  /// Method that returns the user decision on sorting order
  /// ------------------------------------------------------------
  Future<String> getCameraSelected() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.getString(_nameKey) ?? 'name';
  }

  /// ----------------------------------------------------------
  /// Method that saves the user decision on sorting order
  /// ----------------------------------------------------------
  Future<bool> setCameraSelected(String value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.setString(_nameKey, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried out the code and although everything looks right to me, the app won't save the selected camera. Each time I restart the app, it defaults to the back camera.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with defaulting to the back camera each time by removing the widget.initCamera and just referencing the main initCamera as defined at the top of the file.

Comment: By the way, Thanks so much for your help.!